# Mavericks Using Up All Available Memory

Tags: memory, macos

I upgraded to Mac OS X Mavericks. I thought that Mavericks was supposed to use memory more efficiently. It appears that the OS has memory allocation problems. My computer is using up 99.99% of my memory even when it's just sitting idle, turning my iMac into a paperweight. My computer lags and freezes even when it's not doing anything.

Is there anything that I can do, besides upgrading my physical memory?

Comment: I'm the author of the original post... Swap Memory used is also extremely high... 7GB+... As is use of the processor... My iMac is using between 70% - 100% processing power, even when it's idle. I just ran a full restore, clean install after formatting my hard drive. The only things I installed were system updates and Mavericks.

Comment: Can you open up Activity Monitor from Utilities and using the CPU and Memory tabs show what's actually using up your RAM and CPU.

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. That's how I know how much of my CPU and RAM are being used up. Here's what's using everything up: Notifyd, Opendirectoryd, Installd, Perl5.16, Launchd and Kernel_task... All root tasks.

Comment: All I have open is this webpage and Activity Monitor... My CPU usage is 90%, my memory usage is 3.80 GB and swap memory is 7 GB.

Comment: We need to see what Activity monitor shows

Comment: I don't see an option available to upload screencaps. All I had open was Activity Monitor and CPU usage was 70%, Memory usage was 3.73 GB and Swap Used was 7.28 GB. The only things shown running were all root and Mac-specific tasks like Kernel, Finder, Dock, etc. I know that this much CPU/Memory usage is normal for Mavericks... It's all over the internet. All I want to know is should I just upgrade my physical memory since that seemed to be the only thing that solved the problem for other people? I'm irked that someone was allowed to alter/edit my question without my approval.

Comment: I'm on a deadline. So, I really need to get this resolved today.

Comment: It's strange that you're noticing unresponsiveness at idle, but using a lot of RAM is kinda the point of the ram update in Mavericks. Free RAM is a complete and utter waste as far as computing goes: it's hardware you've paid for, you're powering, but is doing absolutely nothing in the present. Optimally, computer systems should use as close to full memory as possible, whilst ensuring that space can be made for vital operations. This is why Mavericks typically uses 99% of RAM: it detects free space and stores file caches to speed up the system. It's strange that it's not properly freeing though

Comment: I restarted in Recovery Mode and Repaired my hard drive using Disk Utility. It said that my disk was fine, but the CPU usage is better... 4% at first. Fluctuating between 3% and 37%. Memory usage is currently 3.99 GB and swap is 0.

Comment: Ran sudo purge and memory usage has dropped significantly, as has CPU usage. Swap memoryis at 0. My computer is now responsive when actually running programs, as opposed to freezing while idle. Thank you. That fixed the problem.

Comment: Update, disk repair and sudo purge do fix the problem... They both need to be done at regular intervals throughout the day every time the system starts freezing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening Terminal and typing in: 
sudo purge

or you can try Memory Clean at 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memory-clean/id451444120?mt=12

BTW: It would be beneficial to post screenshots or use EtreCheck (created by an Apple Support Community User) and copy and paste the results. Etrecheck can be found at http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck