# Reduce Maverick Memory Footprint

Tags: macos, memory

I'm using a macbook air 2014 with 8GB, also running Parallels a lot so wanted to reduce memory usage of OSX.

Already disabled voice dictation that freed up around 500 mb.

Any other tricks/tweaks?

Comment: check out: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118324/mavericks-using-up-all-available-memory?rq=1 http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106171/mavericks-unusually-high-ram-usage?rq=1 http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106697/insanely-high-kernel-ram-usage-over-9gb-in-mavericks?rq=1

Comment: It would help if you posted a screen shot of the Memory tab in    Activity Monitor.

Comment: sure: http://screencast.com/t/FRkOFnBcGLZa http://screencast.com/t/gO9PhYNxjsV http://screencast.com/t/E9mAS5yKs4d